# How to set the domain name and subdomain name on port 80 for same ip address?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I want to set
172.01.03.04 to example.com
and
172.01.03.04 to subdomain.example.com

Both domains should be set to default port 80.

Ubuntu_18.04

Nginx

Laravel 5.5

Need_Help
Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example.com

`server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/www/html/example.com/public;`

```
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
          allow all;
    }
```

}

for subdomain.example.com

`server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        root /var/www/html/subdomain.example.com/public;`

```
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
          allow all;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to `172.01.03.04` and there's a nginx service running on it, listening to port 80. "Setting IP to domain" would be done via your provider's DNS dashboard. For example, here's the guide for [Linode DNS Manager](https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/manager/dns-manager/)

minimal nginx config for `example.com`:

```
server {
    server_name  example.com;

    root         /path/to/example.com/laravel/public;
    index        index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root         /path/to/example.com/laravel/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php;
    }
}
```

for `subdomain.example.com`:

```
server {
    server_name  subdomain.example.com;

    root         /path/to/subdomain.example.com/laravel/public;
    index        index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root         /path/to/subdomain.example.com/laravel/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php;
    }
}
```

Add as separate config files [`example.com.conf` and `subdomain.example.com.conf`] to the nginx configuration [`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`] and restart nginx.

More on nginx server names: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: I have followed your answer but get error when I restart nginx :   "Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: @Faiyaj - could you provide your exact config files and the relevant output from the command `journalctl -xe`?

My examples were pretty minimal and I might have missed something that's causing your existing set-up to fail.

Comment: I have found the problem @gvk .. Your answer is correct but I have to set "listen 80 " before server name .

Answer (score 0):

check the error file

```
sudo nano cd /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

i think you have How to fix “Nginx: [emerg] bind() to failed (98: Address already in use)” this error

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
```

```
fuser -k 80/tcp
```

```
fuser -k 443/tcp
```

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
```

```
service nginx start
```